# Macro assignment to function call

Tags: c, macros, struct, bit-manipulation

Is is possible to define a macro BREF(...):

```
struct bits
{
    int b0:1;
    int b1:1;
    int b2:1;
    int b3:1;
    int b4:1;
    int b5:1;
    int b6:1;
    int b7:1;
}

#define BREF(var,bit) ????
#define BAR 4
#define ALIAS BREF(foo,BAR)

unsigned char foo;
```

such that this statement:

```
ALIAS = 1;
```

expands to this:

```
((struct bits *)&foo)->b4 = 1;
```

and this:

```
int k = ALIAS;
```

to this:

```
int k = ((struct bits *)&foo)->b4;
```

So far, this is my implementation of BREF(...):

```
#define BREF(var,bit) (((struct bits *) &(var))->b##bit)
```

However, this only works if `bit` is a literal numeral. I want to be able to pass in a macro variable that expands into a number. How can I make the C preprocessor expand `bit` before concatenating it to `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extra step of expansion, like this:

```
#define BITATTR(num) b##num
#define BREF(var,bit) (((struct bits *) &(var))->BITATTR(bit))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I've done stringification with two levels of expansion, but never with concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is that the C preprocessor will expand macro arguments *only if they are not being used with the stringizing (`#`) or token-pasting (`##`) operators*.  So, to make it work with a macro that expands to a numeric literal, add an extra layer of macros like so:

```
#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define BREF(var,bit) (((struct bits *) &(var))-> CONCAT(b, bit))
```

With this definition, `bit` is no longer a direct argument of the token-pasting operator, so if it's a macro, it gets expanded before the token-pasting.

Comment: Good attempt, but the problem with this method is that the preprocessor sticks `b` and `EXPAND` together before it even bothers to expand `bit`.

Comment: Oops sorry, you're right, and for exactly the reason I stated!  I mis-tested, but now it's fixed.